# Make two column responsive images of same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-size

I have differently sized images, but want to make them look equal by width and height on the page. What I did:

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src = "assets/img/101.jpg" alt="Null" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#images img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  position: center;
}
```

But they look like that:

[image: screenshot]

They have different height. 
How to make it equal?
Probably I need to crop them by height and center without changing the width. Is it possible?

#### Explanation from the comments

I have suggested that it will probably be nice to crop them, not resize. Center and crop to the size of smaller ones.

Comment: if the image have diffierent height. They wont have the same height in web unless you set their height.

Comment: Do you realize that if you resize the images without keeping the aspect ratio they will look bad? Just saying...

Comment: Yes, I realize that things. That`s why I have suggested that it will probably be nice to crop them, not resize. Center and crop to the size of smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gain more control over your images it's best to switch to background images. You can then use `background-size: cover` to fill out the div.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="image-holder" style="background-image: url('assets/img/101.jpg');">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="image-holder" style="background-image: url('assets/img/101.jpg');">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-holder {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If your images are just static assets it's better to include the image reference in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set both height and width at the same time for an image- it will stretch them out. Have made it a 2-column flexbox along with `col-lg-6` as per requirement.

See demo below:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 50%;
  min-width: 200px; 
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col-lg-6.box {
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class=" col-lg-6 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Null" />
  </div>
  <div class=" col-lg-6 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="Null" />
  </div>
  <div class=" col-lg-6 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="Null" />
  </div>
  <div class=" col-lg-6 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Null" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried and it works as intended, thanks. But I'm trying also to align them photos in two columns using col-lg-6 and for some reason it does not work together.

Comment: @TheKitMurkit made it work alongside `col-lg-6`. Please check and let me know your feedback. thanks